# Timer, Process and sequential access and multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, process, timer

For a project I use an external executable which only allows sequential access due to some resources it uses inside.

There already are a couple of methods that use that resource.

Now I want to `Ping()` that resource through the executable 
to see whether it is available.

But the Timer events may come in while one of the methods is running
and I wanted it to just skip the `Ping()` then.

So I created some `private volatile bool isRunning` but it does not work.
The `Ping` does not see the `isRunning`

What would be a good and lightweight way to get the sequential command execution
that is needed here?

Comment: `volatile` may not be the best way to do this sort of thing; but you *should* see the change from another thread (on an x86-based system).  So, that suggests to me there's something else going on; but I can't tell what that is based solely on your description.

Comment: I have done some refactoring on the code, as it is legacy code that is not very well structured. Now I plan to build a Queue for that jobs, that should do the job.

Comment: I would think trying to figure out what this doesn't currently work might give you some important information.  But, a Queue and a Timer are a bit contradictory.  e.g. if you *need* a ping at a certain frequency, that may be circumvented by a Queue.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I just want to visualize to the user that the resource is available. While another action is running it is not important that the availability gets updated. So, I do not need a certain frequency, it is sufficient to show it in less than 15 seconds after the last job ends.